# can only concatenate tuple (not "unicode") to tuple

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am using **Django 1.5.4**

I am a newbie in Django and i tried to display the image uploaded via admin panel, but unfortunately the url field in the source code for the image is **Empty** and if i change `{{ article.image.url }}` to `{{ article.image }}`, the image url shows up as

```
<img src="media/abyss.jpg" alt="" height="450"/>
```

and when i click the link for image, it says

```
TypeError at /media/abyss.jpg
can only concatenate tuple (not "unicode") to tuple
```

Please Help me.

Settings.py File

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'media').replace('\\','/'),)
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Models.py File

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


   def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s' % self.title

   class Meta:
      ordering = ['-created']

   def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('blog.views.article', args=[self.slug])
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index'),
                       url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'blog.views.article'),
                       url(r'^(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
                       )
```

index.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>PyStack</h1>

    <div>
        {% for article in articles %}
            <img src="{{ article.image.url }}" alt="" height="450"/>
            <h2><a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">{{ article.title|capfirst }}</a></h2>
            <p>{{ article.description }}</p>
            <hr/>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MEDIA_ROOT` should be string not tuple:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'media').replace('\\','/')
```

Trailing comma makes it a tuple:

```
>>> x = (1,)
>>> type(x)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> x + u'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    x + u'foo'
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "unicode") to tuple
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped but Now i get **Page Not Found** when trying **{{ article.image.url }}**

Comment: @AjayKumar Please post that as a new question and mark this one as solved.