# Static Media Image not Found in Django

Tags: python, django

In reference to my Previous Question [can only concatenate tuple (not "unicode") to tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069615/can-only-concatenate-tuple-not-unicode-to-tuple)

Now, I get the following error when i try **GET Request** on **URL** of the Media File.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/media/media/abyss.jpg
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index'),
                       url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'blog.views.article'),
                       url(r'^(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
                       )
```

Comment: what does your url.py look like?

Comment: @AjayKumar please update the question instead of posting it in comments.

Comment: Please see the link in the question itself for all the file info's

Comment: why the url contains /media/media, is this an error?

Comment: @eran Thats because of the `MEDIA_URL = "\media\"`

Comment: What do you get if you request for `http://localhost:8000/media/abyss.jpg`? And `MEDIA_URL` should be `/media/`. Try one at a time, then together.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here's what I did to solve it:
My project structure

```
./django_site
   app1/ 
   app2/
   media/
   django_site/
     settings.py
     #your other basic config stuff in here
```

In settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In urls.py inside sub-directory django_site/

```
#the main url patterns
urlpatterns = patterns('',
#urls
)

"""Here's where we're putting the route to serve media from MEDIA_URL. 
I couldn't get this part to work inside the inital declaration of urlpatterns. 
Maybe you'll have better luck """

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

And then in the template:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image_name }}" height="200" width="400"/>
```

I'm passing `image_name` from a function based view. As it appears, you have to define the `http://somesite.com/media/` url at some point to be able to pull media back from `MEDIA_URL`. I haven't explicitly seen this in the documentation, however, the GET request always seems to fail unless you configure the url route. Now, I pull the file from within the template or directly via url. Hope this helps!